# Problem baking a diffuse texture with a metalic material

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders, baking

Hi so I've been constantly scouring reasons why my bake has been unsuccessful. I was trying to bake all the materials into a diffuse map to use. When I did this only some of the materials would bake while the rest would leave just a black texture. I eventually figured out that using metallic for me caused the black textures. The problem is that without the metallic the look of it changes drastically. Is there a certain way to bake the diffuse map to reproduce the colours without getting rid of the metallic in the shader.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXTwe.jpg

This is what the project looks like with uv baking and how the material is set up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling greatly trying to bake these materials.

Answer (score 1):

You could change metallic to 0, bake the textures and then change it back to what it was. Or add a *Diffuse BSDF* node, connect it to the output and connect the texture to it, and then bake. When you are done baking go back to using the *Principled BSDF* node.